# Parametrized population of a string in bash from 1 to n

Tags: arrays, string, bash, for-loop, echo

Is there an easy way to populate a dynamic string with a size parameter?

lets say, we have:

```
Case N=1:
echo "Benchmark,Time_Run1" > $LOGDIR/$FILENAME
```

however, the run variable is parametric and we want to have all `Time_Run`s from 1 to n:

```
Case N=4:
echo "Benchmark,Time_Run1,Time_Run2,Time_Run3,Time_Run4" > $LOGDIR/$FILENAME
```

and the generic solution should be this form:

```
Case N=n:
echo "Benchmark,Time_Run1,...,Time_Run${n}" > $LOGDIR/$FILENAME
```

Is there a way to do that in a single loop rather than having two loops, one looping over n to generate the Run${n} and the other, looping n times to append "Time_Run" to the list (similar to Python)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop from 1 to `$n`.

```
{
printf 'Benchmark'
for ((i = 1; i <= $n; i++)); do
    printf ',Time_Run%d' $i
done
printf '\n'
} > $LOGDIR/$FILENAME
```

Comment: WHat do you mean? This is the basic way that `printf` is used.

Answer (score 2):

One way to populate the output string with a single loop is:

```
outstr=Benchmark
for ((i=1; i<=n; i++)); do
    outstr+=",Time_Run$i"
done
```

It can also be done without a loop:

```
eval "printf -v outstr ',%s' Time_Run{1..$n}"
outstr="Benchmark${outstr}"
```

However, `eval` is dangerous and should be used only in cases where there is no reasonable alternative.  This is not such a case.  See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).

Comment: eval echo "Benchmark ,Time_Run{1..$n}"|tr -d ' '

Comment: @ufopilot: You don't need an `eval` here. `outstr=$(echo ...| tr ...)` should be sufficient. However, you incorporate the word _Benchmark_ also _n_ times, but according to the OP, this should occur only once at the beginning. Fixing these issues, I think it would be a good idea to post your approach as an answer.

Comment: @user1934428 with blank after Benchmark it's only one time.
  You need eval for the bash range with variable {1..$n}

Comment: I didn't see the blank. If you place code in a comment, enclose it between backquotes. In this way, it is formatted using a fixed space font, and we can recognize where the blanks are.

Comment: `eval echo "Benchmark ,Time_Run{1..$n}"|tr -d ' '`